# php dynamodb - how to do a "hashkey in (key1, key2, key3)" query?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I've been looking at dynamodb as its currently the only hosted fully scalable nosql system out there I can find that takes the headache of db management away.

I currently have an RSS feed indexing system where feed data is inserted into mongodb, then sphinxsearch loops through the entire database and indexes the various fields (well I use main+delta indexes but no need to explain that here).

With sphinx I can then do complex queries and sorting and it gives me an ordered array of article ID's, once I query mongo with those ids I then reorder the mongo array to match the order that sphinx gives me.

```
function prepare_for_mongo($keys){
    $results_keys_mongo = array();
    if(sizeof($keys)>0){
        foreach($keys as $key=>$value){
            $results_keys_mongo[$key] = new MongoID($value);
        }
    }
    return $results_keys_mongo;
}

function sort_mongo_results($documents,$keys){
    $documents_sorted = array();
    foreach($keys as $key){
        $documents_sorted[$key] = $documents[$key];
    }
    return $documents_sorted;    
}

function retrieve_records($keys) {
    $m_keys = $this->prepare_for_mongo($keys);
    if(!empty($m_keys)) {
        $records = iterator_to_array($this->mongodb->find(array(
            '_id' => array('$in' => $m_keys)
        )));
        $records = $this->sort_mongo_results($records,$keys);
    } else {
        return array();
    }
}
```

Now, in my quest to migrate to dynamodb, how can I achieve a similar query with php's dynamodb where I can pass a list of hashkeys (unique hash representing article records) and then dynamo gives me a result of all records containing those hash keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find the solution, the aws sdk function as `batch_get_item` and then I can pass an array of haskey's.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that a solution exists.  SphinxSearch seems to be built to accomplish this task while pointing at a SQL database.  With DynamoDB (NoSQL), you would probably have to write the equivalent of SphinxSearch yourself to index and search the data, while storing the backing indexes in DynamoDB.  The "answer" in this case would be at least a medium-sized development project.